# Its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am getting this error in my console also my app is rendering any element [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpxUJ.png)

Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/static/js/main.c293d6ac.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Send the correct Content-Type response headers for JS/CSS files

Comment: I think this is a server issue, not a react issue

Comment: Maybe you are getting 404 page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.